# How to configure max_in_flight value for deployment

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to have zero downtime deployments when I update my app. The following article says that to configure this feature set instances to whatever value you like to scale the app and then set max_in_flight to the number of instances that are brought down in one go to give a smooth transition.

For example, If instances is 10 and max_in_flight is 5 the the first 5 will be replaced first and then the other 5 replaced after so that the app has zero downtime for upgrades.

I can't see an option to set max_in_flight in the manifest file. I don't know where to configure this. I'm using the bluemix provider.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/high-availability.html

Thanks

Comment: Ah, actually that doc looks like it's for deploying CF platform and not an app on the platform

Comment: No idea on the max_in_flight, but this for 'zero downtime deployments when I update my app': https://www.ibm.com/devops/method/content/manage/practice_high_availability/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **max_in_flight** reference is about Bosh configuration (orchestration technology, managing CF platform itself)
- to have zero downtime during redeployment of the applications you can use blue-green deployment with mapped routes to separately deployed version, more on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

Answer (score 0):

blue-green deployment :https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#blue_green
Or you can try the bluemix service 'Active Deploy'.
Active Deploy allows you to release a new version of your software with no down time. If at any time during the release a problem occurs, Active Deploy allows you to quickly revert back to the original version. You finalize the new version only when it has shown to work properly.
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/active-deploy/